# changing settings in sbt task

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to defined custom task in `sbt` that will run main class in debug mode.

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    fork in run := true
)


lazy val runDebug = inputKey[Unit]("run in debug")

runDebug := {
      javaOptions in run += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" //this doesn't work

      (run in Compile).evaluated 
    },
```

I cannot make `sbt` to set `javaOptions` correctly. How to use `Def.settings` with `inputTask` to define another `inputTask` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tasks cannot modify settings, instead try [commands](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Commands.html) like so

```
commands += Command.command("runDebug") { state =>
  s"""set javaOptions in run += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005""""::
  "run in Compile" :: state
}
```

Comment: sbt never stops to surprise me